# Shopify - Template check within product-loop

Tags: shopify

Does anybody know that is possible to check the template within product-loop? So, if one of the listed product's template is different, somehow I need to know.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the global [`template`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/template) variable to access the name of the template used to render the current page. For example:

```
{% if template contains 'product' %}
  This is a product page...
{% endif %}
```

Or you might want [`product.template_suffix`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/product#product-template_suffix):

> Returns the name of the custom product template assigned to the product, without the `product.` prefix nor the `.liquid` suffix. Returns `nil` if a custom template is not assigned to the product.
>
> **Input**
>
> ```
> <!-- on product.wholesale.liquid -->
> {{ product.template_suffix }}
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> wholesale
> ```

Comment: @levipadre No problems :)